# Remove output of author username and blog link of news snippets from search results

Tags: 7, search, nodes

I currently have this in *template.php* to remove the *'username's blog'* link from blog entries.

```
function phptemplate_links($links, $attributes = array()) {
    unset($links['blog_usernames_blog']);
    return theme_links($links, $attributes);
}
```

How would I go about using unset to remove the *'username's blog'* link from the search results page?

Comment: On my site 'username's blog' isn't in search results. - Also I would be wary of any answers recommending you unset or hide the search result info, because that info contains a number of different things and you probably don't want to get rid of it all.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

To make changes to search results for article content type, Goto `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` and enable the search result custom display.

Then visit `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/search_result` and add or remove the fields as per your requirement.

Comment: How are you able to remove the 'username's blog' link from the search results page? Don't see an option to do that in the way you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

one simple way without any change in template files.. Just add following code in your css.

```
.search-info {
display: none;
}
```

It done all the tricks..

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement using ThemeName_preprocess_search_result() function. Just Refer this link from Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1101554#comment-5345554

```
/**
    * Process variables for search-result.tpl.php.
    *
    * @see search-result.tpl.php
    */
    function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
      // Remove user name and modification date from search results
      $variables['info'] = '';
    }
```

Another solution is that you can override the search-result.tpl.php file in your theme folder. Just remove following snippet from the file:

```
<?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This broke the drupal site and stopped it loading :/

Comment: check the edit of the answer

Comment: Hey, I had already done this to remove the authors name and publishing date for entries but it doesn't remove the user blog URL

Comment: so do you want to hide xyz's blog xx reads information form search results ? xyz: user name xx: number of reads and various other attributes

Comment: I think it is coming $info_split variable, when i did var_dump($info_split) then it showed me lots of attributes. You can unset some of these variables. Just see the comments of search-result.tpl.php

Comment: I printed $info_split it contains the author but not the link

Comment: these solutions didn't work @mohit_rocks

Answer (score 0):

You can find `search-result.tpl.php` file in your drupal instance folder `modules/search`. You need to edit that file to hide the author and date details.

Place this part of code in HTML comments tag.

```
<?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Now, reload the page. In that way you can remove author details.